# How can I change the order that data is inserted into multiple tables with a Script Component in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a script component in SSIS that parses the data into 3 outputs, which in turn are inserted into three tables. The problem is that one of these tables is a foreign key table and depends on the first two tables having their rows inserted first. Put another way, it would look like this:

```
Person
--------
Id
Name
Age

Job
--------
Id
Job Title
Hourly Pay

PersonJob
--------
PersonId (FK to Person.Id)
JobId (FK to Job.Id)
```

How can I have my Script Component insert the parsed output into the Person and Job tables first, and then the PersonJob table after?

Comment: The generally accepted practice here is not to have foreign keys on Staging tables. Even more so: the fewer constraints your staging tables have, the better.

Comment: Agree with @RogerWolf.  However, you can also parse the data twice.  Get the first two tables loaded first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have complete control over the data being parsed into these tables, I ended up creating two Execute SQL Commands in my task flow.

Basically, before my package started on the data flow, I would remove the constraint. Then, once the data flow was complete, I would enable the constraint again. I'm not happy with the process, as I don't like to have to mess with the constraints when it's simply a matter of inserting them into the table in a specific order.

However, I do think it's a lot more efficient than having to parse the data twice or use a staging table. Either way, thanks for the advice!